# "Required 'compute.addresses.get' permission" when trying to create an address in GCP using Ansible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, ansible, virtual-machine, provisioning

I am trying to create a VM in GCP using ansible. I have followed the official tutorial on Ansible's website.
I created the service account and gave it 3 roles: compute.admin, editor and serviceAccountUser. Generated the JSON key and basically copy pasted the code

```
- name: create a address
  gcp_compute_address:
    name: 'test-adress'
    region: "{{ region }}"
    project: "{{ project }}"
    auth_kind: "{{ auth_kind }}"
    service_account_file: "{{ service_account_file }}"
    scopes:
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
    state: present
  register: address
```

This is the output

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "GCP returned
> error: {'error': {'code': 403, 'message': "Required
> 'compute.addresses.get' permission for
> 'projects/sdb20-21/regions/europe-west2/addresses/test-adress-lmao-lol'",
> 'errors': [{'message': "Required 'compute.addresses.get' permission
> for
> 'projects/sdb20-21/regions/europe-west2/addresses/test-adress-lmao-lol'",
> 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]}}"}

I have tried pretty much every fix suggested in this website about this problem, to no avail. If I go to the google cloud "policy troubleshooter" it tells me that the service account does manage to call the api for "compute.addresses.get" with sucess.

The onty thing I cannot do is start another project, for school/credit reasons. Anything else is welcome

Comment: If you actually assigned those roles to the service account, then ansible is not using that service account to create resources. Note you are specifying the `compute` scope. You should be using the `cloud-platform` scope except if you have a technical reason and understand IAM roles and how scopes affect them.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately. Also, I used the compute scope because that's what the Ansible documentation specifies. Also also, pretty sure I'm using the correct account... It has the right "email address" in the JSON file

Comment: Are you provide credentials as module parameter? or environment variable?
If you use environment variable, You should check what projectId is registered in "project" variable, So does "service_account_file" variable.
I recommend to provide credentials as module parameter to clear what values in variables.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but I am in deed using the a module parameter